# дефис между тремя прилагательными, обозначающими цвет

Tags: раздельно-дефис

"Ярко насыщенно-краснокожие". Нужен ли дефис после "ярко"?

Comment: "нужна ли запятая" - похоже, что вы имели ввиду "нужен ли дефис".

Comment: Да, ошиблась, хотела спросить про дефис

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал так:

Ярко-насыщенно-краснокожие.

Одна из функций дефиса - соединение разных слов для описания одного образа. Цвет - это один образ, составляющие этот образ слова должны быть вместе.

Пример: ярко-красный + фиолетово-красный = ярко-фиолетово-красный